# Find S3 Bucket Owner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket, owner

If there is a bucket that I have read/write access on from my AWS account, is there any way to get the CanonicalUser id of the owner?

Reading the ACL Policy seems to be impossible unless you are the owner : /.

Answer (score 10):

Use [get-bucket-acl](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-bucket-acl.html), if you have read permission of the bucket. It would give output like this

```
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "my-username",
        "ID": "7009a8971cd538e11f6b6606438875e7c86c5b672f46db45460ddcd087d36c32"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "my-username",
                "ID": "7009a8971cd538e11f6b6606438875e7c86c5b672f46db45460ddcd087d36c32"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [GET Bucket](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) transaction? It is used for listing objects inside a bucket, and it also returns a tag that, although looks like being the object owner, according to the docs it is the bucket owner:

> **Owner**
>   Bucket owner.
>   Type: String
>   Children: DisplayName, ID
>   Ancestor: ListBucketResult.Contents | CommonPrefixes

Comment: object owner is not bucket owner

Comment: @homm Yeah, but from the question I understood the OP wanted to know the bucket owner...

Comment: Seem like a error in documentation. `ListBucketResult.Contents` is objects in bucket, so `ListBucketResult.Contents.Owner` is object's owner.